# Discord.py: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable In discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to code a little money sys in discord.py, but my def loadMemberData complains

```
def loadMemberData(memberID):
    data = loadData()

    if memberID not in data:
        return Data(0, 0)

    assert isinstance(memberID, object)
    return data[memberID]
```

results in:
File "C:/Users/[...]", line 52, in loadMemberData
if memberID not in data:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

```
def loadData():
    if os.path.isfile(dataFilename):
        if os.path.getsize(dataFilename) > 0:
            with open(dataFilename, 'rb') as file:
                return pickle.load(file)
    else:
        return dict()
```

Comment: Simply your `loadData` function is returning `None`

Comment: ok lol and how to change that? sry haha my python skills are a bit rusty

Comment: Well if you add the function maybe we could help

Comment: sry its added now

Answer (score 1):

If the file exists but has size 0, the `loadData`-function will return `None` (as per default when no `return` is specified). You might want to remove the else clause and unindent the `return dict()` one layer, that way the function will always return a `dict` if no data is available

```py
def loadData():
    if os.path.isfile(dataFilename):
        if os.path.getsize(dataFilename) > 0:
            with open(dataFilename, 'rb') as file:
                return pickle.load(file)
    # default to an empty dict
    return dict()
```